# How to combine two datasets into one model?

Tags: machine-learning

What kind of machine learning model do I use to combine two data sets with different features into 1 binary class prediction? I want to predict 0 and 1. I have one data set with 1000 values and 2 features and I have a second data set with same class (0 or 1) with 3 different features.

Comment: If these are 5 different features, these are totally separate classification tasks.  Why are you trying to make a single model do both jobs?

Comment: what are the features? what are the labels? Are the two labels the same? are the samples in the two datasets the same samples with different features or completely different samples?